# How to notify multiple separate cached Django read-only instances when a view has changed?

Tags: django, caching

I am considering a Django stack for a site with high-frequency read (GET) events and low-frequency write (POST) events.

Suppose there are a large number of read-only instances which are all serving GET events and caching various views. There are a smaller number of non-cacheing writeable instances which handle POST events. These instances are all independent and might be running on separate machines, although they access the same central database.

Now suppose there is a POST event which invalidates, say, a user's e-mail address. Then various views across the various read-only instances need to invalidate their caches.

Is there a standard way to implement this pattern within the Django framework, or do I need to do this myself?

(Or there a much better totally different way to do this?)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like what you really want is a way to invalidate your cache. There is already a lib for that and it handles object level caching as well as automatic cache invalidation so you don't have to write the logic for that. Your use case is very specific but this lib might help. Refer to the lib [django-cacheops](https://pypi.org/project/django-cacheops/0.9.3/)

Answer (score 0):

One way to implement this pattern in Django is by using Django's built-in caching system. You can set up the writeable instances as the "master" cache and the read-only instances as "slave" caches. When a POST event happens, the writeable instance can invalidate the cache for that view and then notify the slave caches to also invalidate their caches.

To achieve this, you can use Django's signals framework. You can create a custom signal that is triggered when a POST event happens and then connect this signal to a function that invalidates the cache and notifies the slave caches. The function can use Django's cache API to invalidate the cache for the specific view and then use a third-party library like Redis or Celery to send a notification to the slave caches.

Answer (score -1):

Basically What you need is to create an API service that can handle GET and POST requests with high frequency. that is very much possible using the Django framework because there is an amazing API tooling ([Django rest framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/))
and also cashing within Django itself with third party apps ([using redis for example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/cache/#redis)).

I don't know the frequency you are talking about but python is relatively slow compared to other languages, you may need to switch to another API framework to make is faster depending on you needs,

if you want to use python for example there are many options:

1. FastAPI Fast, asynchronous framework
2. Falcon  High performing framework
3. Bottle  Fast, simple, light-weight framework

but if you need to use the Django ORM for example, it may very be suitable for you needs.